# Simple React example with state not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

I wrote a simple example in React with a state. I have a button and when I click on this button I want to show a message but I don't see anything in the view and no error in console... can anyone help me? Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>React State</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.14.0/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@0.14.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="clickableButton"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        var myButton = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function() {
                return { clicked: false };
            },
            render: function() {
                    if(this.state.clicked) return <div><button onclick="{doClick}">Click me</button> Clicked!</div>;
                    else return <div><button onclick="{doClick}">Click me</button></div>;
                }
            },
            doClick: function() {
                if(this.state.clicked) this.setState({ clicked: false });
                else this.setState({ clicked: true });
            }
        });
        ReactDOM.render(<myButton />, document.getElementById("clickableButton"));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your braces do not match correctly, remove the redundant brace in `render`:

```
render: function() {
  if(this.state.clicked) return <div><button>Click me</button> Clicked!</div>;
  else return <div><button>Click me</button></div>;
} << REMOVE THIS LINE
},
```

Also you should use capital case for your components, so rename `myButton` to `MyButton`:

```
var MyButton = React.createClass({
...
ReactDOM.render(<MyButton />, document.getElementById("clickableButton"));
```

Now it should work.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I see the button but the click event is not fired: <div><button onclick="{doClick}">Click me</button></div>

Comment: Remove the quotes in `onclick`, also it should be `onClick`: `onClick={this.doClick}`